# Marking search results that are inplace records with a different look/icon

Tags: 2013, search-results, display-template

We're using inplace records as a way of declaring news and guides out-of-date. I really want to be able to display it for users when they search and a search result is out-of-date (record).

On the news itself, I've used the `vtiItemDeclaredRecordOWSDATE` managed property to style the page differently marking it out-of-date.

But when I use a display template for my search results, the managed property `vtiItemDeclaredRecordOWSDATE` is not exposed to the display template. I've added it as a `ManagedPropertyMapping` of course.

If I do a REST call to: `<mysite>/_api/search/query?querytext='MyQuery'&selectproperties='vtiItemDeclaredRecordOWSDATE'` the column is displayed but under the heading: `SP.SimpleDataTable`

Is there any way to retrieve the `vtiItemDeclaredRecordOWSDATE` from within my Display Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this.

In the display template, I call a function placed in another js-file with the element's path as the only attribute. This function then find context and builds a REST url based on the path, retrieving only the vtiItemDeclaredRecordOWSDATE.

Then it checks if there is actually a value in that attribute and if so, finds the element again with jQuery and sets the appropriate styling.

```
function getItemContext(path) {
var clientContext;
$(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', execOperation);
    });

function execOperation() {
    try {
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
        getMoreOnItem(clientContext, path);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
}

function getMoreOnItem(clientContext, path) {
var myPath = "http://sc.ccta.dk/_api/search/query?querytext='* path=\"" + path + "\"'&selectproperties='vtiItemDeclaredRecordOWSDATE'";
$.ajax({
            url: myPath,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                findRecord(data, path);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Fejl" + data);
            }
    });
}

function findRecord(data, path) {
if (data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results.length > 0) {
    var recordDataArray = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[0].Cells.results;
    for (i = 0; i < recordDataArray.length ;i++) {
        if (recordDataArray[i].Key == "vtiItemDeclaredRecordOWSDATE") {
            if (recordDataArray[i].Value !== null) {
                console.log("Denne er posteret!");
                $(".SKATWebItem a[href='" + path+ "']").parent().parent().parent().css("background-color", "#DADADA");
                $(".SKATWebItem a[href='" + path+ "']").parent().parent().parent().css("padding", "10px");
                $(".SKATWebItem a[href='" + path+ "']").parent().parent().parent().prepend("<div class='SKAThistorisk'>Denne meddelelse er historisk og ikke l&aelig;ngere g&aelig;ldende</div>");
                $(".SKATWebItem a[href='" + path+ "']").parent().parent().css("padding-left", "30px");
                $(".SKATWebItem a[href='" + path+ "']").parent().parent().next().css("padding-left", "30px");
                $(".SKATWebItem a[href='" + path+ "']").parent().parent().next().next().css("padding-left", "30px");
            }
            ///console.log(recordDataArray[i].Value);

        }

    }
}
}
```